# ScheduledJob ScriptBlock won't trigger

Tags: powershell

I have a workflow which I am manually putting into suspend:

```
workflow workflowtest1 {

    get-service | export-csv c:\temp\workflow-before.txt -nti
    suspend-workflow
    get-service | export-csv c:\temp\workflow-after.txt -nti
    }

    workflowtest1 -JobName workflowtest1
```

I am able to manually run it using Get-Job | Resume-Job and it works fine.

I am trying to trigger the job to resume using a ScheduledJob:

```
$Trigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At (get-date).addseconds(30)
Register-ScheduledJob -Name WorkScheduledJob `
                      -Trigger $Trigger `
                     -ScriptBlock {Import-Module PSWorkflow; Get-Job -Name workflowtest1 | Resume-Job}
```

This doesn't work, the ScheduledJob triggers successfully, but it doesn't seem to do anything (when I run Get-Job I can see the workflow is still suspended).

If I test using:

```
-ScriptBlock {New-Item c:\temp\new_file.txt -type file}
```

..this works fine

Edit:
I adjusted the Register-ScheduledJob as this real user and ran a more simple command:

```
$adm = "someadminuser1"
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "somepassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($adm, $pwd)
#$Trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup
$Trigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At (get-date).addseconds(30)
Register-ScheduledJob -Name WorkScheduledJob `
                      -Trigger $Trigger `
                     -ScriptBlock {Resume-Job -name workflowtest1}
```

[image]

The ScheduledJob runs successfully, but it doesn't seem to do anything/the workflow is untouched

Comment: Start Schedule Job with Run As Admin.  As Schedule Task doesn't have an environment so PSMODULEPATH is not defined,  Usually you config a service account and then run AS the service account.  The service account has an environment.

Comment: @jdweng How would I run this as SYSTEM as I don't want to deploy a dedicated AD or local Admin account for it

Comment: The Task Scheduler has option to choose a User Account.  Make sure a User account is configured that can run task.  Looks like that is what your already did.